# Python Find all pair by pair intersection in a tree

Tags: python, search, tree, intersection, traversal

I have a tree. I have to traverse throught the tree pair by pair finding the intersection between the two nodes, but for the next pair, I need to use the elements in of previous node found in the previous intersection. I guess the example explains better:

Tree:

A-B-C-D-E

I start with A-B, find the intersection between them. Then I move to B-C, but now I can only use the elements in B that are in the intersection A-B, when I move to C-D I can only use the elements in C that are the intersection B-C, and so on, until the end of the tree.

I am using Python, but I am not necessarily looking for a code, right now I am looking more much for ideas on how to do that efficiently, which alrogithm to use etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by the intersection between two nodes? A-B-C-D-E is kind of a degenerate tree but looks like a linked list to me. Can you show the actual tree structure alongside an output of the traversal?

Comment: The intersection is the set of elements common to both nodes. I used the word tree because it may have branches (or not), so the idea of a list does not always apply.

Comment: E.g.: A = (1,2,3) and B = (2,3,4). The interction of A-B is (2,3). When I move to B-C I can only use (2,3) to compare B to C (find their intersection). Whatever the intersection of B-C is, that is what I can use to find the intersection between C-D and so on.